# Invert the sense of a FOR command?

Tags: windows, batch-file, for-loop, command-prompt

With batch files, it's simple enough to process all files that share a string in their filename or extension, like:

```
FOR /R %F IN (*.EXE) DO @ECHO %F
```

But, what if I want to invert the sense of the file set? Like, process all files that *don't* end in .EXE?

```
FOR /R %F IN (anything-but-exe) DO @ECHO %F
```

I couldn't find anything that seemed to be what I was looking for by reading the output of `FOR /?`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This should be another option:

```
FOR /R %F IN (*.*) DO @if /i not "%~xF"==".exe" ECHO %F
```

Answer (score 4):

```
for /f "tokens=* delims=" %a in ('dir /s /b /a:-d^|findstr /i/e/v ".exe" ') do @echo %a
```

Comment: This will filter out `file tax.exempt.txt` so `findstr /i/e/v ".exe"` is better than using find.  The OP wants a recursive search too.

Answer (score 1):

I have added this answer because there is a potential issue with the currently offered [`findstr.exe` answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/25985524). It uses the search pattern `.exe`, but without stipulating that this should be a literal search pattern. `Findstr.exe` uses a regular expression pattern as its default, which means that the character `.` becomes a wildcard, (for any character). This means it could omit unintended files too, and whilst a filename ending with `jexe`, `lexe`, `_exe` etc. are unlikely, robust code should not assume it impossible.

Here's how it should be done using `findstr.exe`.

Either as a literal search pattern:

```bash
For /F "EOL=? Tokens=* Delims=" %G In ('Dir /A:-D /B /S 2^>NUL ^| %SystemRoot%\System32\findstr.exe /VLIE ".exe"') Do @Echo %G
```

Or as a regular expression pattern, *(where `\` escapes the wildcard `.`, and `$` matches the end of the line)*:

```bash
For /F "EOL=? Tokens=* Delims=" %G In ('Dir /A:-D /B /S 2^>NUL ^| %SystemRoot%\System32\findstr.exe /VRIC:"\.exe$"') Do @Echo %G
```

I have additionally used `2>NUL`, to redirect any potential failure to locate any files, to the NUL device, instead of passing the error message through to the piped `findstr.exe` command.

As a final note, I used `EOL=?` to stipulate another default frontEnd Of Line character. The default in a `For /F` loop is to exclude all lines beginning with a semicolon, `;`. As filenames can legally begin with a semicolon in Windows, we should not exclude those from our `Do` command(s). To prevent that, I used an alternative character, one which is disallowed in a Windows filename, (`<` `>` `:` `"` `/` `\` `|` `?` `*`), in this case I decided upon the question mark.